# Responding an image (via pipe and response.end()) leads into strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used this code to pipe an image to my clients:

```
req.pipe(fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/imgen/cached_images/' + link).pipe(res))
```

it **does** work **but** sometimes the image is not transferred completely. But no error is thrown neither on client side (browser) nor on server side (node.js).

My second try was

```
var img = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/imgen/cached_images/' + link);
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type' : 'image/png'
});
res.end(img, 'binary');
```

but it leads to the same strange behaviour...

Does anyone got a clue for me?

(abstracted code...)

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    Imgen.generateNew(
        'virtualtwins/www_leonardocampus_de/overview/28',
        'www.leonardocampus.de',
        'overview',
        '28',
        null,
        [],
        [],
        function (link) {
          fs.stat(__dirname+'/imgen/cached_images/' + link, function(err, file_info) {
                if (err) { console.log('err', err); }
                  console.log('file info', file_info.size);
                  res.writeHead(200, 'image/png');
                  fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/imgen/cached_images/' + link).pipe(res);
              });
        }
        );
}).listen(13337, '127.0.0.1');
```

`Imgen.generateNew` just creates a new file, saves it to the disk and gives back the path (link).

Comment: Is the pipe code maybe inside a callback?

Comment: oh yes! it is... but does this effects the piping?

Comment: FYI: node version: 0.8.1

Comment: @johannesboyne: Can you verify, after you get half an image, that the image on disk (i.e. generated by `Imgen.generateNew`) is correct? I suspect that may be your culprit...

Comment: i am calling the callback only after writeStream (used to store the img on disk) fires an 'end' event `stream.on('end', [calling the callback]);` so we can be sure, don't we? But of cause i can add a fs.stat befor, do you think I should try this?

Comment: i changed the code and added a fs.stat to get the file size... now it is getting even stranger (IMHO).

I called it several times, sometimes it showed the image completely sometimes not and the `console.log('file info', file_info.size);` hopped between file info 0, and file info 8 **but** it was not like expected, that 0 showed only a part and 8 showed the whole it was random. But file size 8 is quit strange as well, isn't it?

Comment: thx @LinusGThiel ! it really was that problem! :-) node is so blody fast!
Conclusen in my post!

Comment: It should also be noted that ```res.writeHead(200, 'image/png');``` is setting the header 200 to image/png. Currently your code returns Content-Type as application/octet-stream. You probably meant ````writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/png"});````

Comment: Glad to hear that. If `Imgen` is something of your own invention, you might want to convert it to a `ReadableStream` and just `pipe` it directly to `res`... Something like `Imgen.generateNew(params).pipe(res)`.

Comment: @johannesboyne Please add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the problem was: I had 2 different writeStreams! If WriteStream#1 is closed, the second should be closed too and then it all should be piped.

But node is asynchronous so while one has been closed, the other one hasn't. Even the stream.end() was called... well you always should wait for the close event!

Comment: Hey I'm getting some odd behaviour I'm doing: ```res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
 fs.createReadStream(outputFolder + filename + '.png').pipe(res);``` But I'm finding the response in chrome is coming through as raw data. I.e. chrome doesn't notice its an image it says its a document? But it does render the image http://imgur.com/JwP7t7c  http://imgur.com/JTywqcC The mime type is image/png all of my images are png. Should I be closing some stream connection or something?

Comment: I only had a quick read through your question, but it looks like node did send the image string encoded, and not as binary. You could try setting the encoding flag to `createReadStream`:
see http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/fs.html#fs.createReadStream

Answer (score 2):

I've used this before and all that is needed is that in the `function (req, res) {`:

```
var path = ...; 
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type' : 'image/png'
});
fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
```

where `path` is the computed path to the file to send. `.pipe()` will transfer the data from the read stream to the write stream and call end when the read stream ends, so there is no need to use `res.end()` after.

Comment: like i wrote, it does work, but sometimes it only transfers half of the data.
atm i tried all combinations (of cause it is always the same... as you see i am running crazy because of this behaviour)

Look here http://jsfiddle.net/cSGuS/3/

Comment: I think that you might have a call to `res.end()` in there which is ending the `res` before `.pipe(res)` has completed. Could you show the complete context of this code?